# If $g(x) = \text{arctanh}\ (\log x)$, find $g'(x)$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, logarithms

If  $g(x) = \text{arctanh}\  (\log x)$, find $g'(x)$.

I tried to separate the terms first and I got $\dfrac12 (\log(1+\log x) - \log(1-\log x))$.

The answer is $\dfrac1{x(1-\log x)^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT :**

Let $y=\log x$, then you have $g=\text{arctanh}\ y$. Apply chain rule
$$
\frac{dg}{dx}=\frac{dg}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}.
$$